# Keep getting the following error Message=There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 85,Token in error = ) ]

Tags: sql

This is what I am trying to do:

```
SQLStmt = String.Format( _
      "insert into Details (OrderId, GSId, Qty, Each, LedgerId) values ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4})", _
       OrderId, lblGSId.Text, Qty, txtEach.Text, lblLedger.Text)
    'Debug.Write("UpdateSQLStmt=" & SQLStmt & vbCrLf)
    Dim UpdateCommand As New SqlCeCommand(SQLStmt, Cnxn)
    UpdateOK = UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Your query is susceptible to a SQL Injection attack.  Look into using sqlParameter objects to pass values into the query, instead of string concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

Displaying the full query, after `String.Format` call could help you to find the issue.
If you have any non-integer value in the query, make sure they are included in quotes. Also, make sure they are not empty.

For example, if `LedgerId` is empty, your query is:

```
 INSERT INTO Details (OrderId, GSId, Qty, Each, LedgerId) VALUES (42, 3, 5, 6, )
                                                                     No value ^
```

As you can see, this is an invalid query, that could lead to the error message you are seeing.